# How to extend a Numpy array to include x following numbers of each entry

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Given the array:

```
arr=np.array([0,10,20,30])`
```

I would like to end up with the array which extends each of the entries by `x` indices, e.g. when `x=2` to get:

```
array([0,1,2,10,11,12,20,21,22,30,31,32])`
```

Is there a better way to do than this:

```
np.concatenate((arr, arr+1, arr+2))
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30,  1, 11, 21, 31,  2, 12, 22, 32])
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to make use of `numpy.broadcasting`; reshape *arr* to a 2d array and add it to the increasing step array; the broadcasting rule will make a cartesian addition of the two arrays; Flattening the 2d result will give you the output:

```
x = 2
(arr[:, None] + np.arange(x+1)).ravel()
# array([ 0,  1,  2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32])
```

Another approach:

```
x = 2
np.repeat(arr, x+1) + np.tile(np.arange(x+1), arr.size)
# array([ 0,  1,  2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32])
```

Comment: You can try to use `x` in your first solution to make things generic. Just `np.arange(x+1)`

Comment: @kmario23 Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A Python and NumPy mashup solution:

```
In [69]: np.array([list(range(num, num+x+1)) for num in arr]).ravel()
Out[69]: array([ 0,  1,  2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32])
```

---

A little faster solution than the above solution is to use two `for` loops in the list comprehension to avoid explicit array flattening.

```
In [88]: np.array([num+i for num in arr for i in range(x+1)])
Out[88]: array([ 0,  1,  2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32])
```

Thanks to @psidom for the suggestion!